# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value after I try to reloadData()

Tags: swift

I am creating an app that scans barcodes and adds the barcode value (and name and date but working on that later). After I scan the barcode, I call the add method which should add it to my tableview but I am hitting an error at my reloadData().

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var data: [Ticket] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        data = createArray()
    }

    func createArray() -> [Ticket] {
        let video1 = Ticket(number: "123456789", name: "First Name - Last Name", date: "May 18th, 2019, 7 am")
        let video2 = Ticket(number: "123456789", name: "First Name - Last Name", date: "May 18th, 2019, 7 am")

        return [video1, video2]
    }
}

extension FirstViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let ticket = data[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TicketCell") as! TicketCell
        cell.setTicket(ticket: ticket)

        return cell
    }

    func add (_ code: String)
    {
        let tic = Ticket(number: code, name: "First Name - LastName", date: "May 18th, 2019, 10 am")
        print(tic.number1)
        print(tic.name1)
        print(tic.date1)
        data.append(tic)

        self.tableView.reloadData() // Error Occurs Here
    }
}
```

This is where I'm calling the add method from a different controller. The String "code" is the barcode's value:

```
func found(code: String) {
    FirstViewController().add(code)

    viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: Show how and where you call this `add` method.

Comment: Most likely you are creating another instance of `FirstViewController` without the storyboard so the `tableView` outlet isn't being set.

Comment: Yep, your edit proves my theory.

Comment: `FirstViewController()` creates a new instance of the view controller which is **not** the instance in the storyboard. Therefore the outlet is not connected and the code crashes.

Comment: And never call `viewDidLoad` yourself.

Comment: So how should I call my add method from another Controller while passing a String as a parameter?

Comment: You need the **real** reference to the controller in the storyboard, either with segue or with instantiation.

Comment: How are you opening the another view controller from the first view controller?

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you add a barcode using `FirstViewController()`, you are creating a **new** instance of `FirstViewController`, you can use delegation to update the original instance.

First create a protocol with your `add` method

```
protocol BarcodeScanDelegate: class {
    func add(_ code: String)
}
```

Extend `FirstViewController` to inherit `BarcodeScanDelegate` and move the `add` method

```
extension FirstViewController: BarcodeScanDelegate {
    func add (_ code: String) {
        let tic = Ticket(number: code, name: "First Name - LastName", date: "May 18th, 2019, 10 am")
        self.data.append(tic)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Within the 2nd (barcode scan) view controller create a variable that keeps a reference to the above delegate

```
class BarcodeScanViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: BarcodeScanDelegate?

    func addScannedBarcode() {
        self.delegate?.add("BARCODE_HERE")
    }

}
```

Now when you launch 2nd (barcode scan) view controller, assign its variable `delegate` to self

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    ...

    @objc func launchBarcodeScanner() {
        let viewController = BarcodeViewController()
        // or use following if you are using storyboard
        // let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BarcodeVC") as! BarcodeViewController

        viewController.delegate = self // <<<

        self.present(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Got rid of the error but won't add the value of the barcode I scan

Comment: Ended up figuring it out! Thank you for the help and sample project it really helped!

Answer (score 0):

You have the tableView in FirstViewController class in storyboard.

But in this method you are not appending a ticket to the existing array. You are creating new instance for FirstViewController. The tableview is in storyboard and you are creating this FirstViewController instance programmatically. So the IBOutlet will be nil. So it is crashing.

```
func found(code: String) {
    FirstViewController().add(code)//new FirstViewController instance
    viewDidLoad()
}
```

Instead of adding the code from another view controller, pass the code to the FirstViewController using custom delegate and reload the tableview.