# Fill CirleProgressView and save result to UserDefaults

Tags: swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I need help with my little project for university. I have two ViewControllers. 
First - DietViewController 
Second - WaterBalanceViewController (use SPStorkController)

I need to fill CircleProgressView in my DietVC. [image: DietVC]

When I click on `Drink` ->

```
 @IBAction func drinkAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let controller = WaterBalanceViewController()
        let transitionDelegate = SPStorkTransitioningDelegate()
        controller.transitioningDelegate = transitionDelegate
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        transitionDelegate.customHeight = 620
        transitionDelegate.showIndicator = false
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And open SPStorkController - my secondVC
[image: secondVC]

Next, when I click on button `Drink` in my secondVC I must save: how much i just drank. For example call this variable `justDrunk`. In my firstVC I have  `var currentAmountOfWater = Float()`This is the value that will be passed to CircleProgressView. I try to save:

```
@objc func pressButton(_ sender: UIButton){
        print("Hello")

        self.justDrunk = Float(textField.text!)!
        let vc = DietViewController()
        vc.currentAmountOfWater += justDrunk
        vc.currentAmountOfWater += justDrunk
       UserDefaults.standard.set(vc.currentAmountOfWater, forKey: "currentAmountOfWater")

        print(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "currentAmountOfWater"))



        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
```

When I try to print I can see that my value doest't save. Always printed the result of `justDrunk`.

Then I want to use my `currentAmountOfWater` in my firstVC.

In viewDidLoad  `var valueForWater = currentAmountOfWater/maxAmountOfWater

```
waterProgress.progressColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 122/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
       waterProgress.setProgressWithAnimation(duration: 1, value: valueForWater)
```

Please, someone helps me. How to enter data in secondVC, pass data to firsVC and displayed all in CicrleProgressView. And maybe you can write a code that will reset `currentAmountOfWater` to zero every 24 hours.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since your are retrieving the value from storage **immediately**, you **must** execute `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` in order for your changes to get written on disk **immediately**

Here is your updated method

```
@objc func pressButton(_ sender: UIButton){
    guard let justDrunk = Float(textField.text!) else { return }

    self.justDrunk = justDrunk

    let vc = DietViewController()
    vc.currentAmountOfWater += justDrunk
    vc.currentAmountOfWater += justDrunk
    UserDefaults.standard.set(vc.currentAmountOfWater, forKey: "currentAmountOfWater")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    print(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "currentAmountOfWater"))

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Just a side note, do not force unwrap `Float(String)`, user might input a non-numeric string and that could cause a crash in your app.

I would prefer to call delegate method to update the view controller, which I have explained briefly in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56243643/1244597), you can also have a look at [sample project](https://github.com/r-aamir/delegation_example_in_swift)